# Any way of storing the clicked word (from the html) in the separate file in the server?

Tags: python, onclick, cgi

The following html works as "when a user clicks the word "Music", it shows the html page (i.e. 'https://snu.ac.kr/music.html')"

```
<a href"#" onClick="parent.Content.location='https://snu.ac.kr/music.html'; return      
false;">Music</a>
```

My question is : when the user clicks the word in the web, is there any way for the system (the server) to write the clicked word "music" in the separate file in the server using python cgi?

I need to store the user_clicked words in the separate file to perform other task in the server, but I am stuck in proceeding that part...  Any tips would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Javascript to do an [AJAX-style post](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml) in the background to save whatever information you'd like on click.  Then redirect the page on success.